# Error in Spinnaker Pipeline Webhook stage

Tags: spring-el, spinnaker

My pipeline cannot run manually and source json shows pipeline template as invalid. Also states, #stage function could not be mapped to typedvalue. I have similar pipeline stages created from the copy of failing stage and they work as expected. But the parent one is invalid.

```
expressionEvaluationSummary" : { "#stage( #root.execution, 'Get SHA') 
['context']['webhook']['build'['object']['sha']" : [ { "description" : 
"Failed to evaluate [repository_refspec] EL1022E: The function 'stage' 
mapped to an object of type 'class 
org.springframework.expression.TypedValue' which cannot be invoked", 
"exceptionType" : 
"org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException
```

Answer (score 0):

This was missing the pipelineId used in evaluating the expression to resolve to current instance and not of type class